# Force upgrade Huawei from Android 6? Is it still supported by Google

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, huawei

I have a Huawei CAM L21 that I have updated to EMUI 4.1.3 which is the last update I got a prompt for.
The Android OS is Android 6. I don't see any prompt or button for any further update.
Now I am getting messages that I can't use apps e.g. YouTube with the message that Google Play is not supported for this device. I also can not find the icon for Google Play anywhere (I have checked the disabled apps etc)
This error started happening few weeks ago.
I suppose that Google stopped supporting Android 6 recently?
In any case, is there a way to force upgrade from Android 6? What would the steps be? Or is there any solution for this device?

Comment: google stopped supporting huawei for political reasons. you can use alternative stores like f-droid or sideload apk

Comment: Google still supports Android 6, but there are actually 2 different issues that aren't really related here: 1) [Google cannot provide Huawei with Google apps anymore, including Play Stores and Play Services due to the US ban](https://support.google.com/android/thread/29434011/answering-your-questions-on-huawei-devices-and-google-services) 2) According to [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_y6ii_compact-8663.php), Huawei Y6II only received upgrades until Android 6.0 officially. Further than that, you have to resort to custom ROM.

Comment: @AndrewT.: But why did the problem occurred last month only? Did something happened?

Comment: @alecxs: But why did the problem occurred last month only? Did something happened?

Comment: since updated EMUI?

Comment: @alecxs:No I hadn't. I started getting the errors and then updated to the last EMUI